# get file/directory listing on remote host using os.walk()

Tags: python, linux, file, module

Can I get file/directory listing from  a remote host using a  python script which is located on local machine and uses the os.walk() functionality  , If not is there any other python module which could achieve this without passing it to bash ?

Comment: You don’t need *bash* but *ssh* or *ftp*…

Comment: preferably through ssh .

Comment: I have answered it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68053398/6588689