# os.walk remote Linux server

Tags: python, linux, os.walk

Is it possible to have `os.walk()` read the contents of a remote Linux server, without any third-party libraries?

I know that on Windows, we can use UNC paths, for example:

```
os.walk(r"\\server\sharename\path\dir")
```

But how can we do this on Linux? (The remote Linux server is tightly controlled and does not have Samba demon installed; also the local machine is also tightly controlled and is not allowed to have any third-party libraries installed, only the standard Python 3.8 libaries.)

Comment: can you ssh to the remote server?

Comment: Are both machines running Linux? Do you have permissions to mount the remote server?  If so, you can use something like the `sshfs` utility; [guidance](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh). Then walk the structure as if it was a local directory.

Comment: Yes, I can ssh to the remote server. Both servers are running Linux (though one may be CentOS and the other Debian or something else). I'm not sure if we have sshfs or if we are allowed to install it but I can look into it. Thanks.

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Is ssh possible from the local to the remote?  If so why not run  something on the remote to get a file list?  If python is installed on the remote then you already are aware of os.walk.  If not there are plenty of shell commands such as find which can return a filename tree.

Comment: @Vorsprung thanks for your comment. Yes, ssh is possible from the local to the remote machine. I can run python on the remote machine, but I want to `os.walk` from the local machine to various remote machines and look at and compare files between them. I want to do things like get file sizes. I can do `ssh ... ls -l` but would then have to parse and interpret the output, whereas `os.walk` would allow me to access the information more readily.

Comment: Install `sshfs` on the local machine, mount the remote box to an arbitrary directory and "walk" that ... of course there will be permission/ownership issues (I truly hope that you **can't** ssh as root), but it's as close as it gets to Windows/CIFS and UNC names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot directly do `os.walk` in remote machine. But, we can write a similar function, not exactly same functionality, but a best effort approach with the help of `open_sftp`, `listdir_attr` and `paramiko`. One sample I tried.

```
import paramiko
from stat import S_ISDIR

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('ip_address_remote_machine', username='username', password='password', banner_timeout=60)
sftp = client.open_sftp()

        def sftpwalk(dl):
            remotepath = dl
            files = []
            folders = []
            for f in sftp.listdir_attr(remotepath):
                if S_ISDIR(f.st_mode):
                    folders.append(f.filename)
                    #print(dl+f.filename)
                    sftpwalk(dl+f.filename+"/")
                else:
                    # if
                    files.append(f.filename)
            # print (path,folders,files)
            print( remotepath,folders,files)
    
    dl= '/home/generic/Nizam/'
    sftpwalk(dl)
    client.close
```

This can go to remote path passed, list out all directories, and files. Further enhancement can still be tried.

Under Nizam , I have dir1, dir2, dir3 and dir1 has dir11, dir12 with some files.

Output of this is:

```
(u'/home/generic/Nizam/dir2/', [], [])
(u'/home/generic/Nizam/dir1/dir12/', [], [])
(u'/home/generic/Nizam/dir1/dir11/', [], [u'11.txt'])
(u'/home/generic/Nizam/dir1/', [u'dir12', u'dir11'], [u'2.txt', u'1.txt', u'3.txt'])
(u'/home/generic/Nizam/dir3/', [], [])
('/home/generic/Nizam/', [u'dir2', u'dir1', u'dir3'], [])
```